# PayPal Classic error: The seller accepts encrypted website payments only

Tags: coldfusion, paypal

I have a e-Commerce website that has been using US PayPal accounts for processing orders, not the API, just the standard account.   It works fine.

One of my clients is in the UK and is getting an error message that indicates it maybe his account.

> Error: The seller accepts encrypted website payments only. You
>   cannot pay the seller through un-encrypted buttons. Please contact
>   your seller for more details.

PayPal says its not the account.   Is there a difference between US and UK.

The code:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" >
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
  <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="SEOWebstore">
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="#GetSettings.Paypal_Account#">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="#Request.AppSettings.SiteName# Order">
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="#Left(LSCurrencyFormat(10, "international"),3)#">
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="#Total#">
  <cflock scope="SESSION" timeout="15" type="READONLY">
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="#Request.BasketNum#^#Session.User_ID#"        
  </cflock>
  <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="#Request.AppSettings.SiteURL##self#?fuseaction=shopping.checkout&step=ipn">
  <input type="hidden" name="return" value="#Request.AppSettings.SiteURL##self#?fuseaction=shopping.checkout&step=ipn&PayPalCust=Yes">
  <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="#Request.AppSettings.SiteURL##self#?fuseaction=shopping.basket">
  <input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but01.gif" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</form>
```

Comment: It's probably just a copy-paste error, but you're missing a closing `>` on your custom input field.

Comment: Yes it is just a copy and paste error but thanks for the observation

Answer (score 2):

The error message:

> Error: The seller accepts encrypted website payments only. You cannot pay the seller through un-encrypted buttons. Please contact your seller for more details.

appears when you are using a non-encrypted and unprotected PayPal Payments Standard button and you have selected to block payments these payments on your PayPal account (this works for any accounts)

To unblock payments from unprotected and non-encrypted PayPal Payments Standard buttons:

1.Log in to your PayPal Premier account or Business account.
2.Click the **Profile** subtab.
3.In the **Selling Preferences** column, click the **Website Payment Preferences** link.
4.Scroll down to the **Encrypted Website Payments** section.
5.Next to the *Block Non-encrypted Website Payment* label, select the **Off** radio button.
6.Scroll to the bottom of the page, and click the Save button.

Ref. [Encrypted Web Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/encryptedwebpayments/#id08A3I0P017Q)

Comment: it's strange that even I intend to turn this option On, it's still not blocking non-encrypted buttons,